# How to program scrollbar to jump to bottom/top in case of change in QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit area?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, position, qtextedit

How to program scrollbar to jump to bottom/top in case of change in QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit area?
It looks like it doesn't have any controlling function.

Comment: We have two different interpretations! Do you mean a change to the text, or a change to the geometry?

Answer (score 40):

QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit are both inherited from QAbstractScrollArea. The QAbstractScrollArea object provides access to the scrollbar through the verticalScrollBar() method.

Thus, to jump to the top:

```
ui.textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

And to jump to the bottom:

```
ui.textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(ui.textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->maximum());
```

This should work for both QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit.

Comment: I missed that TonyK's answer already solves the problem. TonyK's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the 'ensureCursorVisible' method:

> ```
> void QTextEdit::ensureCursorVisible ()
> Ensures that the cursor is visible by scrolling the text edit if necessary.
> ```

This is not a slot, though, so you can't connect it to any signal -- you'll have to create something yourself that you can connect to the void textChanged() signal.

Disclaimer: I may have misunderstood your question -- I assume you want to scroll down when some text is appended to the text.

Comment: Note that this scrolls both vertically and horizontally which may not be what you want.

Comment: In my case text was not fully shown - this is what helped - Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

When a text edit control is resized, `QWidget::resizeEvent` is called. You just have to override this function in your subclass, and call `verticalScrollBar -> setValue (verticalScrollBar -> minimum())` (or `maximum()`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'd like to develop a terminal client program for a special server. There is a checkbox with which you can lock/unlock the screen. If it is unlocked, then processed incoming packets written to the QPlainTextBox would automatically force scroll bar to be at the bottom (regardless cursor position). Your solution seems promising. I'll give you a feedback later... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have done in Pyqt.

self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().rangeChanged.connect(self.change_scroll)

## --------

```
@pyqtSlot(int, int)
def change_scroll(self, min, max):
    print("cambio", min, max)
    self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(max)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am posting my **Solution** as above solution dint work in my case.

**I want to get the cursor at the beginning of `QTextbrowser`.**

By using [QTextEdit::setTextCursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setTextCursor), you can move the visible cursor where you want:

```
     // Go to beginning
     QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textBrowser->textCursor();
     textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor,1);
     ui->textBrowser->setTextCursor(textCursor);
```

Hope, it will help to some one and save their precious time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using QTextEdit and `textEdit.verticalScrollBar().setValue(0)` doesn't work for me.

In my case, `textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start)` can scroll to the top.