# How to Auto-scroll QT Text Field Widget

Tags: python, pyqt

A code below creates a window with `QTextBrowser` widget. 
For five seconds the new lines of text added to `QTextBrowser` using
its `.insertPlainText()` method. 
As soon as text fills an entire field `QTextBrowser` automatically adds a scroll bar. But it does nothing to scroll down so the last line of text would be always visible (or readable) by the user.

I would like to know how to make `QTestBrowser` scroll down automatically so the last line of the text is always within its text field or visible. How to achieve it?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self._console = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)        
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self._console)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def updateField(self):
        for m in range(5):
            for n in range(100):
                self._console.insertPlainText('%s : '%n)
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = None
    if ( not QtGui.QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dlg = MyDialog()
    dlg.show()
    dlg.updateField()
    if ( app ): app.exec_()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to program scrollbar to jump to bottom/top in case of change in QPlainTextEdit or QTextEdit area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939151/how-to-program-scrollbar-to-jump-to-bottom-top-in-case-of-change-in-qplaintexted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.append` instead of `.insertPlainText` to ensure auto scrolling:

```
    self._console.append('%s : '%n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `QTextBrowser` is sub-classed from `QTextEdit` widget be we can use its `.ensureCursorVisible()` method.

To make `QTextBrowser` scroll down automatically as it is being filled with text all we need to do is to add an extra line to enable its property responsible for this feature:
    self._console.ensureCursorVisible()

Here is the working code solution:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self._console = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self) 
        self._console.ensureCursorVisible()       
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self._console)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def updateField(self):
        for m in range(5):
            for n in range(100):
                self._console.insertPlainText('%s : '%n)                    
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)

if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = None
    if ( not QtGui.QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dlg = MyDialog()
    dlg.show()
    dlg.updateField()
    if ( app ): app.exec_()
```