# Setting the scroll bar to the bottom on PyQt5 (using scrollArea and a gridLayout)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I have a QScrollArea with a QGridLayout within. This said QGridLayout is filled with buttons on a 100x100 grid. I want the vertical scrollbar to start on the bottom instead of the top. I've searched online how to do it, but nothing worked so far.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class IndicSelectWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IndicSelectWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(500, 400)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        for i in range(100):
            for j in range(100):
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(), i, j)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = IndicSelectWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit**: Trying to explain better - I need to scroll to the bottom so when I open the window, the scrollbar is at the bottom and not at the top.

What I have tried:

```
x = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(x)
```

and

```
x = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(x)
```

Comment: your question is unclear, explain better please

Comment: @eyllanesc I've edited it, trying to explain better. What I need is to scroll to the bottom, instead of getting the default scrollbar position (top)

Comment: what is `x` in `self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(x)`?

Comment: @eyllanesc it is `self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the scrollbar geometry is updated when:

- The widget is set to the QScrollArea.
- The QScrollArea is made visible.
- The size of the QScrollArea changes.
- The widget size changes if it is visible.

So when placing the widget first and then the buttons, the QScrollArea is not notified of it, so there are 2 solutions:

- Move the scrollbar an instant after showing.

  ```py
      for i in range(100):
          for j in range(100):
              self.gridLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(), i, j)
      QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.handle_timeout)

  def handle_timeout(self):
      x = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
      self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(x)
  ```
- Set the widget to the QScrollArea after the buttons were placed.

  ```py
  class IndicSelectWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(IndicSelectWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
          self.resize(500, 400)
          self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
          self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self)
          self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
          self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
          self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

          self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
          for i in range(100):
              for j in range(100):
                  self.gridLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(), i, j)

          self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
          x = self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
          self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(x)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Although this question has already got an answer, but, I had somewhat similar problem, which was unsolved even after trying the @eyllanesc 's solution.

So, I'm sharing what worked for me.

I got the solution from another post, quick-link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879340, though his solution is for somewhat different topic.

Solution:

```
# inside __init__ method
self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().rangeChanged.connect(
    self.scrollToBottom,
)

# new function in same class
def scrollToBottom (self, minVal=None, maxVal=None):
    # Additional params 'minVal' and 'maxVal' are declared because
    # rangeChanged signal sends them, but we set it to optional
    # because we may need to call it separately (if you need).
    
    self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
    )
```